# C# Try/Catch from User Input Checking for Enum List

Tags: c#, enums, try-catch

I am trying to learn C# and I am really struggling. I badly needed help. I have this task to wrap the statement in a try/catch block and have it print "Please enter an actual day of the week." to the console if an error occurs. I managed to get if the user input is true or not based on the enum but I can't manage to catch the false part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I made the enum list in seperate class named OneWeek and this is my code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the current name of the day.");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string test = input.ToLower();
        OneWeek.DaysOfTheWeek dayParse;
        bool inputParse = Enum.TryParse(test, out dayParse);
        try
        {

            if (inputParse == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thank God it's " + input);
            }

        }

        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an actual day of the week.");
            
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an actual day of the week.");
            
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
```

Thanks to all who answered! Tried all suggestions and it helped. I also found the answer on the suggested thread. You guys made my day. Thank you!

This is the end result of my code. Just changed some of the variables but the goal is the same.

```
try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the current name of the day.");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            string test = input.ToUpper();

            OneWeek.DaysOfTheWeek day;

            if (Enum.TryParse<OneWeek.DaysOfTheWeek>(test, out day))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are right! Today is  " + test + "!");
            }

            else
            {
                throw new OverflowException();
            }
     

        }

        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an actual day of the week.");
            
            
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
```

Comment: You don't need try/catch if you are using `Enum.TryParse`, this method not throws and that's reason why it was created.

Comment: `if (Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out OneWeek.DaysOfTheWeek dayParse)){}else{}`... TBH you have many variables that are not needed and to much bloat for a simple check.

Comment: You shouldn't be using exceptions this way. Exceptions are for actual errors occurring, not for controlling the flow of a program. You kind of allude to this: "I can't manage to catch the false part". This is because you should be testing for false, not for an exception being thrown.

Comment: I'll add even though I gave an answer, @tnw is 100% correct. Other than learning, don't take this as a good strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the current name of the day.");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    string test = input.ToLower();
    if(Enum.TryParse(test, out var dayParse))
        Console.WriteLine("Thank God it's " + input);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an actual day of the week."); 
  
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
```

Answer (score -3):

You aren't actually going to get an exception, because you are handling your values fairly safely (Good).

If you really want an exception, you need to throw one:

```
if (inputParse == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thank God it's " + input);
}
else 
{
   throw new FormatException("Please Enter a real day of the week");
}
```

I'd also then change the catch to:

```
catch (FormatException fex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fex.Message);            
}
```

or, alternatively, handle the enum less safely:

```
try
{
   OneWeek.DaysOfTheWeek dayParse = Enum.Parse(test);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // write error
}
```

Comment: `You aren't actually going to get an exception` the OP wont see it because the `TryParse` handles it; an exception is still thrown, but handled.

Comment: `if (inputParse == true)` is not a good style. Write `if (inputParse)`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I tried to copy & paste the original code as much as possible to show what it replaces.

Comment: @AustinTFrench I agree as well, nothing wrong with leaving constructive feedback when one sees it :). An answer isn't expected to include "here's how I would do it" necessarily (many opinions on this), but addressing the issue at hand. An explanation as to "why" it's not a good style would be appreciated so one understands.

Comment: @Codexer where are you seeing that? ` If ( Enum.TryParse(test, out foo)) { ... } else { throw new exception() }` would catch...